# Is Fox Kit cageable?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Is the [Fox Kit](http://www.wowhead.com/item=64403/fox-kit) cageable and giftable in WoW? If I spend 200 Baradin Hold commendations to buy it, am I able to put it in a cage and give it to someone in my guild?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is cageable. See this screenshot part:

[image]

Comment: 559 Unique pets?? Well done on your grand collection! I am not even near that yet